# On (sums of) multivectors and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I have a doubt about multivectors and linear independence.

Let $w_{1}$, $w_{2}$, $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$, $v_{3}$ be elements of some $n$-dimensional vector space, and assume that $v_{1} \wedge v_{2} \wedge v_{3} \neq 0$. Clearly, if both $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ are in the span of $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$, $v_{3}$, then for any $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ there is $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\left(v_{1}+ \mu w_{1}\right)\wedge \left(v_{2}+ \mu w_{2}\right)\wedge v_{3} = \lambda \left(v_{1} \wedge v_{2}\wedge v_{3}\right).
\end{equation}

I am interested in the converse of this statement. More precisely, is it true that, if for some $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\lambda \neq 0$ such that equation \eqref{eq1} holds, then each of $w_{1}$ and $w_{2}$ is in the span of $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$, $v_{3}$?

EDIT: When $\lambda\neq 0$, equation \eqref{eq1} expresses the condition that the span of the vectors $v_{1}+ \mu w_{1}$, $v_{2}+ \mu w_{2}$, $v_{3}$ is equal to that of $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$, $v_{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false, take $\mu=1$, $w_1=v_2+v_3+v_4$ and $w_2= v_1+v_3+v_4$, where $v_4\not\in \text{span}(v_1,v_2,v_3)$. Then,
$$(v_1+\mu w_1)\wedge (v_2+\mu w_2)\wedge v_3=(v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4)\wedge (v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4)\wedge v_3=0=0\cdot(v_1\wedge v_2\wedge v_3).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Would requiring $\lambda \neq 0$ make the statement true?

Comment: I have edited the question, as I realized that the equation expresses the equality of the spans only provided $\lambda \neq 0$. Sorry about that.

Comment: In fact, I believe that the claim holds now, because $ \mathrm{span}\,(v_{1}+\mu w_{1}, v_{2}+\mu w_{2}, v_{3}) = \mathrm{span}\,(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$ exactly when both $v_{1}+\mu w_{1}$ and $v_{2}+\mu w_{2}$ belongs to $\mathrm{span}\,(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3})$.